# Error "index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection" C# WPF vs2013

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2013

I have this problem: a C# WPF (VS 2013 Pro, .Net Framework 4.0) standalone desktop application that works very well on all Windows operating systems with one exception: on Windows XP I get this error:

"index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection".

The error comes out on a DataGrid (event MouseDoubleClick or with a ContextMenu), in a TabControl (there are 26 tabs, as the letters in the latin alphabet (A, B, C....)) when I choose a record to modify from the datagrid and open a form with the data for that record (like formName.ShowDialog()). The strange thing for me is that all the numbers are ok, I mean the index is 0 (the first record of the datagrid) and also the real id of the record is ok.

This is the code (the error is on the ShowDialog); I also tried to insert a try catch around showDialog() to see what happens and so I got the error.

```
 private void dataGridElencoPazienti_MouseDoubleClick(object sender,    MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Persona paziente = getRigaPaz();

        if (paziente == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Prova a selezionare la riga cliccando col pulsante sinistro e poi col destro e quindi selezionare l'opzione desiderata !", "Selezione riga", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            return;
        }

        FormCartellaPaziente formCartellaPaz = new FormCartellaPaziente(datiUtente, idAzienda, paziente, this);

        this.Hide();
        formCartellaPaz.ShowInTaskbar = true;
        //this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        formCartellaPaz.ShowDialog();

    }


 private Persona getRigaPaz()
    {
        int idPaziente = 0;
        DataRow datarow = null;
        DataRowView pazienteSel = null;
        Persona paziente = null;

        if (dataGridElencoPazienti.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Prova a selezionare la riga cliccando col pulsante sinistro e poi col destro e quindi selezionare l'opzione desiderata !", "Selezione riga", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Exclamation);
            return null;
        }

        pazienteSel = (DataRowView) dataGridElencoPazienti.SelectedItem;

        try
        {
            datarow = pazienteSel.Row;
            idPaziente = Convert.ToInt16(datarow["id"].ToString());

            paziente = new Persona();
            paziente = personaDao.read(idPaziente, 0);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Errore selezione paz - FormCasellarioPazienti: 309 + ---" + ex.ToString());
        }

        return paziente;
    }
```

Thank you
Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible there is no column id?
The exception should then be triggered by the following line:

```
idPaziente = Convert.ToInt16(datarow["id"].ToString());
```

I suggest you to check if the column exists and has a value to convert to an Int16 type.

Btw, you don't have to a `ToString()` before a `Convert.ToInt16`. It will do without..

Comment: Thanks you for your very rapid answer. There is a column id. The app works everywhere except Windows XP. Thanks for the advice with ".toString()", too.

Comment: Do you know which exact line is triggering the exception?

Comment: With the try catch around ShowDialog I think it's right there...I mean when it tries to call ShowDialog. This is why I don't understand...all the work has already been done without errors before this call...the object is ok, the form, etc.

Comment: What is the StackTrace telling you?

Comment: Now I don't have it because on this pc with Windows 7 everything works fine. I will post the stacktrace this evening, I mean after about 4-5 hours.

Comment: I put "solved" for the above answer, although it was not the solution for my problem but it gave me an idea so I found that it was a missing column in the datagrid. Thank you :-)